# Html links don't work with localhost?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, localhost

Is this true? I'm working on an mvc3 application in visual studio and I want the image I'm using as the header to be a link back to the home page, but since I'm just running it locally I'm using this line as the code:

```
<a href="localhost:60060">
<img src="../../Content/images/LionLabs.png" alt="Lion logo">
</a>
```

This doesn't work though! am I doing something wrong, or is it just that localhosts can't be used as this?

I also just tried using a javascript method as the href to refresh the page, but that didn't work either :(

Comment: "This doesn't work though!" is not very descriptive. **What** doesn't work? What do you expect that is not happening?

Answer (score 7):

Since links by default start at the domain, there is no reason to specify it. You can just use `/`.

```
<a href="/">
    <img src="../../Content/images/LionLabs.png" alt="Lion logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML links work just fine with localhost:

```
<a href="http://localhost:60060/">
    <img src="../../Content/images/LionLabs.png" alt="Lion logo">
</a>
```

The issue here is that just using `localhost:60060` attempts to use a relative path, so the browser is actually looking for `http://localhost:60060/localhost:60060/`, which, of course, is an invalid path.

Also, you should not use absolute paths when linking between pages of your application, because that becomes a nightmare when you need to change domain names (like, deploying your application to the web).

To make your code more MVC friendly, do this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/LionLabs.png")" alt="Lion logo">
</a>
```

What's happening here is that the ASP.NET MVC `Url` helper is supplying the proper path information when the page is served out to the user, so it automatically accommodates any changes in the server.  It also allows you to use your `Routes` to best effect, because you can easily change the route (ie the URL) of a link but still use the same controller and view.

Answer (score 1):

The links for `<a href="">` don't differ from the links for `<img src="">` .

You shouldn't use absolute path, because, when you deploy your project, the site name will not be localhost:60060.

For main page use

```
<a href="/"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `href` as `localhost:60060`. It should be a page (may be `default.html` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<a href="localhost:60060">
    <img src="../../Content/images/LionLabs.png" alt="Lion logo">
</a>
```

To this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/LionLabs.png")" alt="Lion logo">
</a>
```

---

**Why?**

It's better to use `@Url.Action` as that will use any custom routing you set in Global.asax. Can you imagine modifying every single link reference on a complex site if you have to change your url routing? :)

Use `@Url.Content`, as that will correctly resolve to the root of your application, taking away the uncertainty of using `../` or `../../` or `../../..`. It's cleaner!